# When insert elements of php array in table mysql what kind of data should be ? Only string?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, type-conversion

I have to insert elements of multi-dimensional php array into table mysql but i don't know what kind of method should be used there.

First create the table

```
CREATE TABLE earthquakes (
  milliseconds BIGINT,
  latitude FLOAT,
  longitude FLOAT,
  magnitude FLOAT,
  depth FLOAT,
  source VARCHAR(2),
  region SMALLINT,
  serial VARCHAT(16)
);
```

Should I add the length of the characters even for the other columns?

Now the code to insert elements:

```
$array = array(
 array(12345678901112145,-35.4905,167.7843,7.5,450.4,"E",134,"2017-01-10-134"),
 array(12345678901112145,35.4905,-167.7843,3.2,45.4,"U",13,"2016-01-10-14"),
 array(12345678901112145,-35.4905,-167.7843,10.0,4,"I",1,"2016-01-10-1")
);


$data = array();
foreach($array as $row) {
 $milliseconds = mysql_real_escape_string($row[0]);
 $latitude = mysql_real_escape_string($row[1]);
 $longitude = mysql_real_escape_string($row[2]);
 $magnitude = mysql_real_escape_string($row[3]);
 $depth= mysql_real_escape_string($row[4]);
 $source= mysql_real_escape_string($row[5]);
 $code= mysql_real_escape_string($row[6]);
 $serial= mysql_real_escape_string($row[7]); 


 $data[] = "($milliseconds,$latitude,$longitude,$magnitude,$depth,'$source',$code,'$serial')";
}

$values = implode(',', $data);


$sql = "INSERT INTO earthquakes (milliseconds,latitude,longitude,magnitude,depth,source,region,serial) VALUES $values";
```

My doubt is if the code is correct but especially if i have to add `" "` double quotes or single quotes for each element (each value that add to the table).

I hope you help me and understand my english :(

**UPDATE**

this is result if i echo `$sql`

```
INSERT INTO earthquakes (milliseconds,latitude,longitude,magnitude,depth,source,region,serial) VALUES (12345678901112145,-35.4905,167.7843,7.5,450.4,'E',134,'2017-01-10-134'),(12345678901112145,35.4905,-167.7843,3.2,45.4,'U',13,'2016-01-10-14'),(12345678901112145,-35.4905,-167.7843,10,4,'I',1,'2016-01-10-1')
```

Comment: Did you check the value of `$values`? I think you query will give an error after `VALUES`

Comment: what is the result?..just `echo $sql` and show that here

Comment: @Jana the result where ?

Comment: @Swellar why do you think this ?

Comment: Have you tried to echo the result of `$values`?

Comment: yes not i update question (Y)

Comment: just echo next to `sql=INSERT ... line`  and put `exit;`..and you will get the output

Comment: i tried this in phpfiddle so i must delete mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: @Jana i don't understand if the values must be inside quotes

Comment: @Borja you don't need to use quotes when you put values through variables...it automatically setup that..but when you try to insert the values directly quotes must be there..got it?

Comment: Sorry Jana :( what do you mean with "to insert the values directly quotes" ? but for example if i use quotes could be a problem ?

Comment: `var $x ='test; $sql=INSERT INTO tabel(name) VALUES($x)'` -->this is indirect..`$sql=INSERT INTO tabel(name) VALUES('test')` -->this is direct

Comment: hmm i'm understanding, but in my case in VALUES there's a string...so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this :-

```
 $array = array(
 array(12345678901112145,-35.4905,"222",7.5,450.4,"E",134,"2017-01-10-134"),
 array(12345678901112145,35.4905,-167.7843,3.2,45.4,"U",13,"2016-01-10-14"),
 array(12345678901112145,-35.4905,-167.7843,10.0,4,"I",1,"2016-01-10-1")
);

//----------------------------
 connection to db is necessary to use mysql_real_escape_string function
//----------------------------

$sql = "INSERT INTO earthquakes (milliseconds,latitude,longitude,magnitude,depth,source,region,serial) VALUES ";

foreach($array as $row) {
     $milliseconds = mysql_real_escape_string($row[0]);
     $latitude = mysql_real_escape_string($row[1]);
     $longitude = mysql_real_escape_string($row[2]);
     $magnitude = mysql_real_escape_string($row[3]);
     $depth= mysql_real_escape_string($row[4]);
     $source= mysql_real_escape_string($row[5]);
     $code= mysql_real_escape_string($row[6]);
     $serial= mysql_real_escape_string($row[7]); 
     $sql .="($milliseconds,$latitude,$longitude,$magnitude,$depth,'$source',$code,'$serial'),";
}
$sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
excute the sql here.
```

If the column type is varchar then you have to add '' single colon to the values.

Comment: i don't understand: where i have to add quotes ?

Comment: see in the line ---
`$sql .="($milliseconds,$latitude,$longitude,$magnitude,$depth,'$source',$code,'$serial'),";`
Source and serial has single quotes because their column type is varchar in db

Comment: yes, results are same. I was just giving you hint about where to put single quotes and also did refactor the code little bit, removed extra array and implode function. thanks :)